# Proportional Editing Falloff

Tags: edit-mode, lattice

Anyone know of any scripts or tutorials to create a new falloff type?  I'm thinking something along a sine wave.

Here's a screenshot.  I've got a lattice attached to a text, and I want to add a sinusodial falloff to modify the mesh.

[image]

Comment: Please explain more fully your question.  Do you have a screen capture or diagram or a texture that might illustrate your goals?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Warp Modifier with Texture of your choice including sinusoidal.

There exists three or more modifiers that are relevant.

- the wave modifier
- the warp modifier which can take a texture such as a sine texture.
- the displace modifier

Other techniques

- weight painting and weight modifiers
- texture to affect modifiers

[image]

Above is the warp modifier in action.  Rather plain ... no texture.

[image]

Closeup Fall Off with texture. Image Above.

[image]

Warp Modifier with Wood Sine Texture. Image above.

The warp modifier produces results similar to user gestures of

**proportional editing**.

The blue cube has a high vertex density.  The from and to are animated in rotation.

[image]
[image]

Results of the wave modifier. Sinusoidal influence. Image Above.